# Update the first and last records only amongst many duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in Access named `Spells` which holds patient spells (where a patient has a spell within a hospital). It's structure is as below:

```
| ID | SpellID | MultipleSpell | FirstSpell | LastSpell |
|----|---------|---------------|------------|-----------|
| 1  | 1       | False         |            |           |
| 2  | 2       | True          |            |           |
| 3  | 2       | True          |            |           |
| 4  | 3       | False         |            |           |
| 5  | 4       | False         |            |           |
| 6  | 5       | True          |            |           |
| 7  | 5       | True          |            |           |
| 8  | 5       | True          |            |           |
```

The `MultipleSpell` column indicates that there are multiple occurrences of the spell within the table.

I'd like to run query which would update the `FirstSpell` column to `True` for records with the IDs of `1`,`2`,`4`,`5`,`6`. So basically, where a Spell is the first one in the table, it should be marked, in the `FirstSpell` column.

I would also then like to update the `LastSpell` column to `True` for records with the IDs of `1`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`8`.

The reasoning for this (if you're interested) is that the table links to a separate table containing the name of wards. It would be useful to link to this other table and indicate whether the ward is the admitting ward (`FirstSpell`) or the discharging ward (`LastSpell`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the first using:

```
update spells
    set firstspell = 1
    where id = (select min(id)
                from spells as s2
                where spells.spellid = s2.spellid
               );
```

Similar logic (using `max()`) can be used for the last spell.